# Build pages not showing on admin panel?

Tags: content-management-system, sulu

As you can see here: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVfts.png . I have build some pages from templates but they are not showing in admin panel. When I go for example to : `http://sulu-dev.lo/contact`, it opens that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the doctrine-dbal transport layer and do you have some kind of special character (dot, dash, ...) in your webspace configuration? There is currently an [issue in Jackalope Doctrine DBAL](https://github.com/jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal/issues/305) which causes this behavior. Simply change the webspace key, use `bin/adminconsole sulu:build --destroy` to initialize Sulu again.

The `--destroy` option deletes all the existing data. If you don't want to do that you should move the `/cmf/<webspace>` node to match the new key using something like the [PHPCR Shell](http://phpcr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/phpcr-shell/) on your own.